# Transaction simulation failed: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation…ocessing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x1

Tags: spl-token, transfer

when I transfer nft to my another account. It makes error.

```
export const createWalletKey = async () => {
  const bs58 = require("bs58");
  const bs = bs58.decode(secretKey);
  const wallet = Keypair.fromSecretKey(bs); // get wallet keypair
  const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");

  connectWithMetaplex(wallet);
};
```

```
export const connectWithMetaplex = async wallet => {
  const bs58 = require("bs58");
  const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");
  const bs = bs58.decode(anotherSecretKey);
  const toWallet = Keypair.fromSecretKey(bs); // get wallet keypair
  const metaplex = Metaplex.make(connection).use(keypairIdentity(wallet));
  const { nft } = await metaplex
    .nfts()
    .create({
      uri: "",
      name: "JERRY NFT",
      sellerFeeBasisPoints: 100,
    })
    .run();

  const fromTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
    connection,
    wallet,
    nft.mintAddress,
    wallet.publicKey,
  );

  console.log("fromTokenAccount", fromTokenAccount.address.toString());

  const toTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
    connection,
    wallet,
    nft.mintAddress,
    toWallet.publicKey,
  );

  console.log(LAMPORTS_PER_SOL);
  const transaction = new Transaction().add(
    createTransferInstruction(
      fromTokenAccount.address,
      toTokenAccount.address,
      wallet.publicKey,
      LAMPORTS_PER_SOL * 10,
      [],
      TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    ),
  );

  const blockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
  transaction.feePayer = await wallet.publicKey;
  transaction.recentBlockhash = await blockHash.blockhash;
  console.log(transaction);
};
```

I have 10 SOL in devnet :(

Comment: Please post the full error in the body of your question

Comment: What secret key are you making your wallet from? Is it your provider's secret key?

Answer (score 4):

`Custom program error: 0x1` implies that you have insufficient funds to execute the transaction.

1. You are trying to transfer `LAMPORTS_PER_SOL * 10` lamports between two accounts.
2. You mentioned that you have exactly 10 SOL in devnet.

While, at first glance, the source account might appear to have sufficient funds to cover the transfer, you also need to consider that the source account must pay the network fee.

Try reducing the transfer amount. Note that you can query the network fee by using the [`getFeeForMessage` API](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getfeeformessage).

Answer (score 2):

As the others have said the problem is insufficient SOL,

here is how to get SOL or lamports in devnet / testnet / mainnet:

```
    const airdropSignature = await connection.requestAirdrop(
        keypair.publicKey, 2 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL);

      const latestBlockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

      await connection.confirmTransaction({
        blockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
        lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockHash.lastValidBlockHeight,
        signature: airdropSignature,
      });
```

for Anchor tests, add `provider.` in front of the `connection` in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

comment resoudre une transfer Custom program error: 0x1 implies that you have insufficient funds to execute the transaction.